# Porting Phonegap Android asset into Phonegap Windows

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, cordova

I have developed  android app using phonegap. Now I want to develop same app for windows phone.

I have downloaded windows sdk in my windows 7 and did the require setup to create cordova app. After that I created sample app. To run my android asset code , just copying its files into www folder is enough...?

Or

What more I need to do for getting this to be worked ...?

Guide me on this to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing to do is to try it and see what happens!

But yes, you just need to copy the contents of the www folder of the Android app to the www folder of a new Windows Phone PhoneGap project.

You might find you might have to make minor modifications to things like CSS because of the differences in how the mobile browsers render the web pages (since the Android app will run on a webkit browser frame whilst the Windows app will run on an Internet Explorer browser frame).

You might need to set the 'Build Action' property for any image resources you copy across to the Windows Phone using Visual Studio to get the images to render.

Comment: Please can you reply to my post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621952/windows-phone-8-cordova-placing-a-file-in-a-different-path

Answer (score 1):

Yes copy the files but be careful not to overwrite  existing files. The Cordova.js file is platform specific, as are other .js files that are created in the new project.

You also need to 'include in project' in Visual Studio otherwise the files copied to www are ignored. Do this in the solution browser on the right pane in VS.

Remember the browser is IE as compared with WebKit in Android so some CSS, HTML and Javascript may need to be changed. If you have used a propagation stop to prevent scrolling in WebKit, this may not work in IE and the touch event model is completely different. This MS guide might help:

http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/11/15/adapting-your-webkit-optimized-site-for-internet-explorer-10.aspx