# windows phone 8 Cordova - placing a file in a different path

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cordova, windows-phone

I am very new to VisualStudio and porting a cordova/phonegap application from android to windows phone 8.

So I created a new project using **createTemplates.bat** and imported it in my VS2012 Express.

The core result is one **www** folder containing **img/css/js** and **index.html**; it works fine and I manage to launch it and deploy on my device.

Because the application is quite big, I want to create a new sub-folder call **subfold** (under img), and placing **picture.jpg** in there so in solutionExplorer I have **img/subfold/picture.jpg** (even if it is hidden); but I cannot use picture.jpg while I can use it if it's in **img**.

- How can I do that? Is it a limit of VS 2012?

I am 100% sure that I use the proper path.
Another notable thing is that in SolutionExplorer View, the subfolder and its content are disabled (look at "attivita" below) and **Build Action property** does not exist while it exists and set to 'Content' if the image is inside img

[image]

Comment: Right-click on the /img folder and check its properties, and compare them with the properties of the /subfold folder. Let me know if there are any differences.

Comment: there is no difference in the two properties menus and everyone just contains the Misc/Folder Name

Comment: What errors are you getting when you try to reference the image files?

Comment: Why is the folder ghosted like that? How did you create the folder? Did you create it from within the Visual Studio Solution Explorer, or did you create it from the Windows file explorer?

Comment: I copied the folder of the android project, so from Windows Explorer ... that might be the problem, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot I can see that the icon for the folder is ghosted out, this means that the folder exists in the file directory, but isn't included in the Visual Studio solution. You can right-click on the folder and choose the option to include the folder in the solution. You may also need to add each of the items in the folders to the solution via the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the absolute path for Windows Phone and not the www folder, this is what i have write for Android Windows Phone8 and iPhone

```
if( /Android|BlackBerry Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    //android absolute path
    path = cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory;
} else if (isWindowsPhone) {
    //windows phone absolute path
    path = "//";
} else {
    //iphone absolute path
    path = cordova.file.documentsDirectory;
}
```